# Filling between an ellipse and a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to shade from the line QV to the edge of the ellipse.  How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, eucal, yfonts, setspace, sectsty, enumitem, amscd, caption, tikz, tikz-qtree, mathtools, inconsolata, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot, pxfonts, xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\raggedright\underline}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3.25,0) -- (5,0) node[scale = .8, fill = white] at (-1.625,0) {$a$};
\draw (0,-3.25) -- (0,3.25) node[scale = .8, fill = white] at (0,1.25) {$b$};
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\draw[blue] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
\draw (0,0) -- (2.59808,1.5) node[scale = .8, fill = white] at (1.29904,0.75) {$a$};
\filldraw (-3,0) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (-3.2,-0.25) {$A$};
\filldraw (3,0) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (3.2,-0.25) {$P$};
\filldraw (0,-2.5) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (-0.25,-2.7) {$D$};
\filldraw (0,2.5) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (-0.25,2.7) {$B$};
\filldraw (1.75,0) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (1.5,-0.25) {$F$};
\filldraw (2.59808,1.5) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (2.84808,1.75) {$Q$}; 
\filldraw (0,0) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (-0.25,-0.25) {$O$};
\draw (2.59808,1.5) -- (2.59808,0);
\filldraw (2.59808,0) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (2.34808,-0.25) {$V$};
\filldraw[inner color = pink!70!, outer color = blue!40!black] (0,0) -- (0.875,0) arc (0:30:0.875cm);
\node[scale = .8, fill = white] at (0.875,0) {$ae$};
\node[scale = .8] at (1,0.28) {$E$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101207/12571) to a related question can be useful here.

Comment: How can I find the intersection of line VQ with the ellipse?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  @Qrrbrbirlbel: Is this perhaps s/w generated code?

Comment: @dustin If you find that an answer best solves your problem for you, you can show your appreciation through accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark. This shows that the problem was already solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to **clip** the ellipse. You can get some coordinate with `intersections library` if you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\draw[blue] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm); 
\begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm); 
    \fill[blue!15] (2.59808,1.5) rectangle (3,0);  
\end{scope}
\draw (2.59808,1.5) -- (2.59808,0);  
\draw (-3.25,0) -- (5,0) node[scale = .8, fill = white] at (-1.625,0) {$a$};
\draw (0,-3.25) -- (0,3.25) node[scale = .8, fill = white] at (0,1.25) {$b$};   

\filldraw (3,0) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (3.2,-0.25) {$P$};
\filldraw (2.59808,1.5) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (2.84808,1.75) {$Q$}; 
\filldraw (2.59808,0) circle (.07cm) node[scale = .8] at (2.34808,-0.25) {$V$};

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very simple and intuitive solution. +1

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `intersections` library to find the coordinate where the ellipse and the line from *V* to *Q* intersect.

1. Name the paths you want to intersect:

   ```
   \draw[name path=ellipse, blue] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
   \draw[name path=line VQ] (2.59808,1.5) -- (2.59808,0);
   ```
2. Use the `name intersections` key to find the intersection. (It will be available as `(Q'-1)`, in case of more than one intersection, TikZ append `-<number of intersection>` at the name.)

   ```
   name intersections={of=line VQ and ellipse, name=Q'}
   ```
3. Calculate the angle of that point with the `calc` library. (As the center of the ellipse is `(0,0)` we get directly the angle from the center.)

   ```
   let \p{Q'} = (Q'-1),
       \n{Q'} = {atan2(\x{Q'}/3cm,\y{Q'}/2.5cm)}
   in
   ```

   In the following path you can use `\n{Q'}` for the angle of the intersection point.
4. Draw/fill/pattern/… the path between *V*, *P* and the intersection *Q'*.

   ```
   (2.59808,0) -- (3cm,0cm)                                                 % from V to P
   arc[x radius = 3cm, y radius = 2.5cm, start angle = 0, end angle=\n{Q'}] % from P to Q'
   -- cycle;                                                                % back to V
   ```

### Code

Or in one entire path:

```
% Preamble:
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

% TikZ picture:
\draw[name path=ellipse, blue] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
\draw[name path=line VQ] (2.59808,1.5) -- (2.59808,0);

\path[name intersections={of=line VQ and ellipse, name=Q'}]
    let \p{Q'} = (Q'-1),
        \n{Q'} = {atan2(\x{Q'}/3cm,\y{Q'}/2.5cm)}
    in [
        draw=green,
        fill=green!50
    ] (2.59808,0) -- (3cm,0cm)
      arc[x radius = 3cm, y radius = 2.5cm, start angle = 0, end angle=\n{Q'}]
      -- cycle;
```

### Output

[image]

## Use named coordinates and not hard-coded numbers, and let TikZ/TeX do the calculations for you.

Take a look at the following code. I have used named coordinates that get labeled semi-automatically. These named coordinates are used throughout the whole TikZ picture.

Hopefully, the comments in the code are helpful enough.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc,fadings,intersections}
\tikzset{
    mark at/.style args={#1 with #2}{
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark connection node=n#2,
            mark=at position #1 with {\node[font=\footnotesize\strut] (n#2) {$#2$};}
        },
        decorate
    }
}

\newcommand*{\myXradius}{3cm}
\newcommand*{\myYradius}{2.5cm}
\newcommand*{\myOverlap}{0.25cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\small}]
% Step 1: Place coordinates and label them.
\foreach \p/\x/\y/\pos in {%
    O/          0/          0/below left,
    A/-\myXradius/          0/below left,
    B/          0/ \myYradius/above left,
    D/          0/-\myYradius/below left,
    P/ \myXradius/          0/below right%
}   \coordinate[label={[name=n\p]\pos:$\p$}] (\p) at (\x,\y);

% Step 1': Place special coordinates and label them (same syntax as before)
\coordinate                      [label={[name=nQ]above right:$Q$}] (Q) at (30:\myXradius);
\path let \p{Q}=(Q) in coordinate[label={[name=nV]below      :$V$}] (V) at (\x{Q},0); % V is Q projected on the x axis

% Step 2: Draw the lines
\draw[mark at=1.625cm with a] (O) -- (180:\myXradius + \myOverlap);
\draw[mark at=1.625cm with b] (O) -- (  0:\myXradius + \myOverlap);
\draw                         (90:\myXradius + \myOverlap) -- (270:\myXradius + \myOverlap);
\draw[mark at=.5 with a]      (O) -- (Q);
\draw[name path=line VQ]      (V) -- (Q);

% Step 3: Draw the ellipses
\draw[                    red] (O) circle  [  radius = \myXradius                       ];
\draw[name path=ellipse, blue] (O) ellipse [x radius = \myXradius, y radius = \myYradius];

% Step 4: Find the intersection of the ellipse and the line between V and Q ...
\path[name intersections={of=line VQ and ellipse, name=Q'}]
    let \p{Q'} = (Q'-1),
        \n{Q'} = {atan2(\x{Q'}/\myXradius,\y{Q'}/\myYradius)}
    in [
        draw=green,
        fill=green!50
    ]
% ... and draw/fill it ...
    (V) -- (P)
    arc[x radius = \myXradius, y radius = \myYradius, start angle = 0, end angle=\n{Q'}]
    -- cycle
% ... and define a special name to it, as (Q'-1) will be lost after the path.
    coordinate (Q') at (Q'-1);

% Step 5: Draw little circles where the coordinates are.
\foreach \p in {O,A,B,D,P,Q,V,Q'} \fill (\p) circle [radius=1.5pt];

% Step X: I have not changes this.
\filldraw[inner color = pink!70!, outer color = blue!40!black] (0,0) -- (0.875,0) arc (0:30:0.875cm);
\node[scale = .8, fill = white] at (0.875,0) {$ae$};
\node[scale = .8] at (1,0.28) {$E$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]