# TikZ: clipping and shade or fill drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have re-written some code I wrote 3 months ago from here [Filling between an ellipse and a line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101554/filling-between-an-ellipse-and-a-line)

However, I cant fill in the smaller triangle no matter what I try.

What I have tried so far is:

```
\begin{scope}                                                                  
 \clip (S) -- (F) -- (V) -- (S);                                              
 \filldraw[bottom color = cyan!50!blue, top color = green!20]                 
 (S) -- (F) -- (V) -- (S);                                                    
\end{scope}
```

and

```
\begin{scope}                                                                  
  \clip (S) -- (F) -- (V) -- cycle;                                              
  \filldraw[bottom color = cyan!50!blue, top color = green!20]                 
  (S) -- (F) -- (V) -- (S);                                                    
\end{scope}
```

and

```
\begin{scope}                                                                  
      \clip (S) -- (F) -- (V) -- cycle;                                              
      \filldraw[bottom color = cyan!50!blue, top color = green!20]                 
      (S) rectangle (V) -- (S);                                                    
    \end{scope}
```

I have tried more but I am not going to list them all.  The new code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{cal, intersections, arrows}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
      draw = black, label = {#1}},
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
    extended line/.style = {shorten >=-#1, shorten <=-#1},
    extended line/.default = 1cm,
    one end extended/.style = {shorten >=-#1},
    one end extended/.default = 1.25cm, line cap = round, line join = round,
    >=triangle 45]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{2.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}

    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(A\)}] (A) at (-3, 0) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below right: \(P\)}] (P) at (3, 0) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(D\)}] (D) at (0, -2.5) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {above left: \(B\)}] (B) at (0, 2.5) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(F\)}] (F) at (\c, 0) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(O\)}] (O) at (0,0) {};

    \draw (0, -3.25) -- (0, 3.25) node[scale = .75, fill = white,
    inner sep = 0cm, pos = .7] {\(b\)};
    \draw[name path = xline] (-3.25, 0) -- (5, 0) node[scale = .8, fill = white,
    inner sep = 0cm, pos = .2] {\(a\)};
    \draw[red, name path = circle] (O) circle (3cm);
    \draw[blue, name path = ellipse] (O) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
    \path[name path = line] (2.25, 3) -- (2.25, -1);

    \path[name intersections = {of = circle and line, by = P1}];
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {above: \(Q\)}] (Q) at (P1) {};
    \path[name intersections = {of = line and xline, by = P2}];

    \draw[black] (Q) -- (P2) node[fill = black, big dot = {below right: \(V\)}]
    (V) at (P2) {};
    \path[name intersections = {of = line and ellipse, by = P3}];
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {right: \(S\)}] (S) at (P3) {};

    \draw (O) -- (Q) node[scale = .75, pos = .5, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm]
    {\(a\)};
    \draw[one end extended] (F) -- (S) node[scale = .8, pos = .5,
    fill = white, inner sep = 0.03cm] {\(r\)};

    \begin{scope}
      \clip (S) rectangle (P);
      \shadedraw[blue, outer color = blue!30!black, inner color = red!30]
      (O) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

So no matter what I do, I cant fill in `(S) -- (F) -- (V) -- cycle`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what is `.center` do that corrects the problem.

Comment: The `.center` part chooses the `center` anchor of the node, thus a coordinate and not a node. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `S`, `F` and `V` are nodes and not coordinates.

You see, when you connect nodes with `--` (or any other path operator) TikZ takes care that you only connect their border.

If you do

```
\draw[green,thick] (S) -- (F) -- (V) -- cycle;
```

you will get

[image]

TikZ will carefully connect the nodes. But this doesn’t create one closed area (the `-- cycle` operator also doesn’t seem to have any effect, because the last stored move-to point will be `V` after the line from `F` to `V` has been drawn.) This is usually what you want (for drawing lines between nodes).

In your case though, you want to create an enclosed area. I am assuming you want to use the `center` anchor of the nodes because … well that’s probably the only sane solution.

I also advice to use the `backgrounds` library and the `on backgrounds layer` style to make sure that the area (both actually) will be drawn *under* the lines and nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, arrows, backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
      draw = black, label = {#1}},
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
    extended line/.style = {shorten >=-#1, shorten <=-#1},
    extended line/.default = 1cm,
    one end extended/.style = {shorten >=-#1},
    one end extended/.default = 1.25cm, line cap = round, line join = round,
    >=triangle 45]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{2.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}

    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(A\)}] (A) at (-3, 0) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below right: \(P\)}] (P) at (3, 0) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(D\)}] (D) at (0, -2.5) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {above left: \(B\)}] (B) at (0, 2.5) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(F\)}] (F) at (\c, 0) {};
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(O\)}] (O) at (0,0) {};

    \draw (0, -3.25) -- (0, 3.25) node[scale = .75, fill = white,
    inner sep = 0cm, pos = .7] {\(b\)};
    \draw[name path = xline] (-3.25, 0) -- (5, 0) node[scale = .8, fill = white,
    inner sep = 0cm, pos = .2] {\(a\)};
    \draw[red, name path = circle] (O) circle (3cm);
    \draw[blue, name path = ellipse] (O) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
    \path[name path = line] (2.25, 3) -- (2.25, -1);

    \path[name intersections = {of = circle and line, by = P1}];
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {above: \(Q\)}] (Q) at (P1) {};
    \path[name intersections = {of = line and xline, by = P2}];

    \draw[black] (Q) -- (P2) node[fill = black, big dot = {below right: \(V\)}]
    (V) at (P2) {};
    \path[name intersections = {of = line and ellipse, by = P3}];
    \node[fill = black, big dot = {right: \(S\)}] (S) at (P3) {};

    \draw (O) -- (Q) node[scale = .75, pos = .5, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm]
    {\(a\)};
    \draw[one end extended] (F) -- (S) node[scale = .8, pos = .5,
    fill = white, inner sep = 0.03cm] {\(r\)};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (S) rectangle (P);
        \shadedraw[blue, outer color = blue!30!black, inner color = red!30] (O) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
      \end{scope}
      \filldraw[bottom color = cyan!50!blue, top color = green!20] (S.center) -- (F.center) -- (V.center) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]